# Android Face Recognition

Tags: android, opencv, computer-vision

I tried to setup OpenCV using the modified Crystax NDK but did not succeed ( I managed to compile using CygWin but dont know where to go from there.) Is there a Simpler class library I can use which will do simple face recognition routines? All I need to do is spot the faces and compare them perhaps. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an `android.media.FaceDetector` class in the Android SDK. Maybe it will help you.

Comment: this class will only detect faces :(

Comment: face detection != face recognition.